# Find and append the related class in Jquery

Tags: jquery, append

My app has a HTML structure like this:

```
    <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2018</h2>
    <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2017</h2>
```

And I want to append my HTML template under related class via jQuery. E.G.

```
    <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2018</h2>
    <div>2018 content</div>
    <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2017</h2>
    <div>2017 content</div>
```

First of all, get my parent class data:

```
    var array = $('.timeline__section h2').map(function () {
                return $.trim($(this).text());
            }).get();
```

Then I used jQuery.inArray function:

```
    if (jQuery.inArray(year, array) === 1) {
                console.log("yes");
    }
```

Its working.

But now, I need append my HMTL template under related class. Tried this trick but its not working good. (Appended my HTML everywhere, not related area.)

```
if (jQuery.inArray(year, array) === 1) {
$($(".timeline__section h2").text(this)).append("<div class=\"col-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch\">"");
}
```

What's the problem and what is the right way for this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method insert content to the end of element, but you need to insert content after element. So use [`.after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
$('.timeline__section h2').after(function () {
  return "<div>year content</div>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline__section">
  <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2018</h2>
  <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2017</h2>
</div>
```

Also if you have custom data for every year, use bottom code

```
var data = {
  2018: '2018 content',
  2017: '2017 content'
}
$('.timeline__section h2').after(function () {
  var year = $(this).text().trim();
  if (data[year] != undefined)
    return "<div>"+data[year]+"</div>";
});
```

```js
var data = {
  2018: '2018 content',
  2017: '2017 content'
}
$('.timeline__section h2').after(function () {
  var year = $(this).text().trim();
  if (data[year] != undefined)
    return "<div>"+data[year]+"</div>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline__section">
  <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2018</h2>
  <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2017</h2>
  <h2 class="milestone font-md bold my-3 ml-md-3 ml-5 my-md-5">2016</h2>
</div>
```